# драйвер rtl8811au не компилируется вместе с ядром

Tags: android, драйвер, mobile-development, кросс-компиляция, ядро

Я пытаюсь скомпилировать драйвер rtl8811au под Android, но возникает проблемма, драйвер пропускается при компилировании

**ссылки:**

ядро: https://github.com/likkai/ksu_kernel_xiaomi_lisa версия 5.4.242

компилятор: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/clang/host/linux-x86/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r13/clang-r450784d/

драйвер: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au

**файлы:**

[drivers/net/wireless/realtek/Kconfig](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/files/14547904/Kconfig.txt)

[drivers/net/wireless/realtek/Makefile](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/files/14547906/Makefile.txt)

Driver path: drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtl8812au

[out/.config.txt](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/files/14547895/config.txt)

***компиляция:***

содержимое $P

```
$ echo $P 
O=out ARCH=arm64 CC=clang CLANG_TRIPLE=aarch64-linux-gnu- LLVM=1 LLVM_IAS=1 CROSS_COMPILE=/home/erophey7/tc/clang-r450784d/bin/llvm-
```

компиляция ядра

```
$ make -j$(nproc --all) $P > ../make_out.txt || exit $?
lib/lib.a:nmi_backtrace.o: no symbols
$
```

[make_out.txt](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/files/14547961/make_out.txt)

modules_install

```
$ make -j$(nproc --all) $P INSTALL_MOD_PATH=modules INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 modules_install > ../modules_install.txt
$
```

[modules_install.txt](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/files/14547969/modules_install.txt)